# Execute *.js if month is December

Tags: javascript

Ok, I give up.

I'm trying to make this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    n = d.getMonth();

    if (n == 11) {
       src="extrafiles/effect/snow.js";
    }
});
</script>
```

call "snow.js" whenever the month is december.

Won't work though.
Ideas ?

EDIT:

Maybe this is a better approach ?

> if ( d.getMonth().match(11) ) {
>         //do call snow.js;
>     }

EDIT2:

This works for determining season, tweakable down to the month

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;
if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
//beginning of script
START JS FILE VIA ???
//end of script
}
</script>
```

Comment: That code will just throw an error since you have no quotes around the value of `src`. Secondly, that's just assigning a value to a variable, not running a script.

Comment: Hmm, but I couldn't I read the variable and check if it matches "11" ? (if I knew how...). I'll quote the exampe...

Comment: Instead of changing the `src` of an element, I recommend just calling a function `snow()` if `n === 11` instead of having a dynamic import like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.write to add the script

```js
if (new Date().getMonth()===11) document.write('<script src="https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/myhomepage/snow.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: Perfection. And merly a single line !

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like that :

```
  if (n === 11) {
    let myScript = document.createElement("script");
    myScript.setAttribute("src", "https://www.example.com/snow.js");
    document.body.appendChild(myScript);
    makeSnow();
  }
```

or in ES6 mode :

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
  async function load() {
    let say = await import('./snow.js');
    say.makeSnow();

  }
</script>
<button onclick="load()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It would help the OP if you explained what your code is doing.

Comment: While the first looks promising, (I suppose I gotta combine it with d.getMonth), it won't really work. [I'm kinda bothered that I can't use a direct filepath] .The second one is neat, but I don't want to have to press a button...

Comment: @Rye The button press is an example, you could just `import()` without it.

Comment: Sadly enough even if I do use that implementation, it still doesn't call the *.js. Kinda weird that noone seems to have had any use for such simple check...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `import` to import the file based on your condition. You could also import the file anyway and just call your function from that file inside of your conditional.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(async () => { // same as $(document).ready(async function(){
        const month = new Date().getMonth()
        if (month === 11) {
          const effect = await import('./snow.js')
          effect.run()
        }
      })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

This is an example of just importing the file at the start

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const effect = await import('./snow.js')
      
      $(async () => { 
        const month = new Date().getMonth()
        if (month === 11) {
          effect.run()
        }
      })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Note that this will throw an error on Stack Overflow because that file doesn't exist but I have verified that it works locally.

Since you've shown the file, I can see that it doesn't actually export anything so `import` won't work for you here. Instead, you're going to have to retroactively add the script to the DOM

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const s = document.createElement('script')
        s.type = 'text/javascript'
        s.src = 'https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/myhomepage/snow.js'
        document.body.appendChild(s)
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I uploaded the snow.js to https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/myhomepage/snow.js could you try and see if it works if called from there ? (I have it here locally, with your example... but it won't call.. I mean it *is* december... so it should trigger alright) (Maybe it's my browser being the issue ?)[amusingly enough, putting your example after a regular "<script src =" blabla.js"> will cancle the regular script huh]

Comment: No idea what machine you are running from, but on Android (Firefox) and Windows 10 (Firefox), the *.js is not called - at all. Is this snippet of yours only suited for certain scripts types ?

Comment: The snow file doesn't export anything so you won't be able to use `import`

Comment: I've edited the answer with an alternative.